# How to select all variables in a dataset and set to proc summary?

Tags: sas

Suppose I have a dataset full, and I want to select all variables and put them in the var statement in the proc summary statement. Is there an easy way to do this? How do I select all variables in the select statement?

```
proc sql noprint; 
    select * into :all separated by " "
    from full;

    %put all = &all.;

    proc summary data=full print;
      *var &list of variables from dataset;
      class type;
      output out=work.summary;
    run;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When in doubt, try `_NUMERIC_` (or `_CHARACTER_` or `_ALL_` in other similar situations):

```
proc means data=sashelp.class;
var _numeric_;
run;
```

FWIW, your approach was wrong, but there is a similar approach that could work.

```
proc sql;
select name into :namelist separated by ' '
from dictionary.columns
where libname='WORK' and memname='FULL' and upcase(type)='NUM';
quit;
```

That goes into the dictionary tables (similar to PROC CONTENTS output datasets) and pulls the variable names into a list.

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably just use the default list syntax.  Get the order from proc contents and the list first and last variables.  For example.....

```
proc contents data = sashelp.class position;
```

Assume w is first variable listed and n is the last, then

```
proc summary data=full print;
      var w--n;
      class type;
      output out=work.summary;
    run;
```

Note that you need 2 dashes for this type of list.
If you have sequentially numbered variables like `x1 x2 x3 x4 x5` etc.
You would do

```
var x1-x5;
```